# Why does quoting password-variable in curl lead to authorization failure? (Bash)

Tags: database, bash, variables, curl, authorization

I have a very specific problem with bash and curl.

What we do is:

- reading a password from jenkins and paste it to a config-file (i don't have access to the password)
- read parameters from config-file in bash (host, user, password, etc.) and store it in variables
- post something with curl to a database and store the result in a variable

Recently we added shellcheck to our deploy-scripts and therefore we need to put the variables in quotes.

That's the request we want to send (shellcheck-approved):

```
result=$(curl -s -XPOST "${dbURL}" --header "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n "${dbUser}:${dbPwd}" | base64)" --data-binary "blabla")
```

And here's the error message we get in return:

*{"error":"authorization failed"}*

It does work, when I unquote the password-variable (**"${dbUser}":${dbPwd}**). But then spellcheck complains, that I need to put all variables in quotes. Also it does work on another machine with different password (which I have no access to either).

It is the same, when I use `--user username:password`. So it seems like the problem lies within the password.

Using google and testing the procedure (without the curl) with different special characters couldn't solve it either.

Has anyone experienced something like this?

Edit1: 
This is an extract from jenkins-deploy-file ..

```
stage('config files') {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "${env_params.db_password}", variable: 'db_pw')]) {
            sshagent(credentials: ["${env_params.user}"]) {
                sh "echo \"dbPwd=${db_pw}\" >>  environment_variables/config.properties"
```

This is how the shell script stores the password ..

```
dbPwd=$(grep ^"$dbPwd" <PATH>/config.properties | cut -d "=" -f2)
```

Comment: I would start by replacing `echo -n "${dbUser}":${dpPwd}` with `printf '%s' "$dbUser:$dbPwd"`. Also, how *exactly* are you setting `dbPwd` in the first place?

Comment: The unquoted parameter expansion is subject to word-splitting and pathname generation; it's possible that your process that sets `dpPwd` did so in a way that anticipated (and thus now requires) word-splitting and pathname expansion to be performed.

Comment: It's possible the password variable is somehow garbled in a way that word splitting "corrects" -- like maybe having trailing whitespace in the value. It's going to be hard to troubleshoot without access to the password. Can you set up a test account that you *do* have the password to, and see how that behaves?

Comment: Most likely, the password has trailing white space (space, new line, \r, ...). Run the script with '-x' to find out more information. Also, consider sharing the code that read the password from the config file

Comment: Could also be leading whitespace in the password/user, or that the password itself contains multiple consecutive whitespaces.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for your reply. I added code-samples for the reading from jenkins and reading from config-file parts.

Comment: `dbPwd` is defined using an old value of the same variable? What's the old value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your support.
It seems like there are trailing whitespaces in the password-storage.
I removed them using sed and now it works.

```
dbPwd=$(grep ^"$dbPwd" <PATH>/config.properties | cut -d "=" -f2 | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just set the password in another file and use the content of the file as your password variable.